# Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive

Tags: angular, passive-event-listeners

I am facing the following issue in each and every browser while clicking an event.  I am using angular5 application. due to this, my application responding very slowly

```html
**[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> 
event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. 
See <URL>**
```

Comment: With my angular app the browser dev tools are blaming zone.js for the violations.  I wonder if that is on any zone.js contributor's desk to address.